# Jasper text field display list of values from json as comma separated value

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I have a json as below 
"markets": [ { "id": "1001", "name": "val1" }, { "id": "1002", "name": "Val2" }, { "id": "1003", "name": "val3" } ]

I am trying to display as following in jasper jrxml text fields 
val1, Val2, val3.

i defined my field expression as follow

```
<field name="market" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="markets*.name"/>
```

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement x="80" y="40" width="100" height="16" uuid="903a6728-3a7a-4d1a-9b70-cd8da7a11c7f"/>
            <textElement>
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{market}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

However only one value is displayed i.e. val1.

how to display list of values.

Thanks
Anjana.

Comment: anyone has come acros this need

Comment: Please check [How to create a report that uses a remote JSON data source](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-create-report-uses-remote-json-data-source).

Comment: Thanks for followup however this link provide information on using json in jrxml. I am looking at using a list data type of json into single field.

Comment: Did not understand it. Please, can you post the expected output?

Comment: expected output is val1,Val2,val3. However i am getting value of only val1.

Comment: has anyone come across similar issue . can you pls guide